# redirect from http to https flew off

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, cpanel

I ran into a problem - that the redirect from http to https did not work for a whole day, the site was connected to cpanel - the site worked fine for 10 days - no work was done - as a result, the redirect flew off and then returned on its own

file.htashes - not touched at all

hosting confirmed the problem - but why and because of what did not say that you can look at it in the logs or in cpanel to find out - what is the cause of this problem!

Comment: "hosting confirmed the problem" - How did they "confirm" this if it's now working OK again? And you haven't touched anything? Sounds like only your host knows the answer to this one? It would seem that somebody did something...

Comment: @MrWhite Well, I demanded an explanation from them and am still waiting for an answer! they just attached logs that at such and such a moment - the site on http gave 200 response

Comment: How are you redirecting HTTP to HTTPS? In fact, update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file (I assume that is where you are redirecting HTTP to HTTPS?) - that "might" shed some light on what could possibly cause the redirect to fail. (Maybe something else failed as well?) How did _you_ know the redirect failed for 1 day?